# Is my code a performance killer?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, datetime

I am showing the value of the timer.php through AJAX in index.php . However I am concern about the performance of this, if it is a server killer if there are 30 people online, and things like this. Do you suggest me some edits?

Thank you.

index.php

```
<script language='JavaScript'>
setInterval( 'SANAjax();', 1000 );

$(function() {
SANAjax = function(){

$('#dataDisplay').load('timer.php');

}
 });

</script>
<div id="dataDisplay"></div>
```

timer.php

```
function time_difference($endtime){
    $days= (date("j",$endtime)-1);
    $hours =date("G",$endtime);
    $mins =date("i",$endtime);
    $secs =date("s",$endtime);
    $diff="'day': ".$days.",'hour': ".$hours.",'min': ".$mins.",'sec': ".$secs;
    return $diff;
}   

$future_time = mktime(0, 0, 0, 9, 19, 2011);
$now_time = strtotime("+2 hours");
$end_time = $future_time - $now_time;
$difference = time_difference($end_time);
if ($future_time <= $now_time ) { echo "Date reached"; } else { echo $difference; };
?>
```

Comment: Short answer: Yes, it is. Could you not do the same thing in JS?

Comment: Exactly, there is no reason to do this in PHP at all, and even if you did need PHP to get the time from a database or something, there's no reason to make another request every second instead of just doing the difference calculation in JS every second. Of course, all this was covered in your last question, you're just asking the same thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your server specs and number of clients, this could quickly become a server-killer.

The multiple calls to a file every second will quickly put a lot of load for nothing though, so best practice calls for using a javascript timer countdown. I particularly like this one: http://stuntsnippets.com/javascript-countdown/

And for the jQuery implementation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myDate = new Date(); //Retrieve actual date
myDate.setTime(this.getTime() + (3600 * 2)); //Add two hours

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#time").countdown({
        date: myDate.toGMTString(),
        onComplete: function( event ){
            $(this).html("completed");
        },
        leadingZero: true
    });
});
</script>

<p id="time" class="time"></p>
```

This should be enough, no more need for PHP calls and the client does everything.

Comment: I define "serving killing" in this case as "why would you ever exercise your server for this kind of nonsense when the browser could carry that load just as well and actually better (in most cases)". *for nothing though* is the operative statement.

Comment: @Jared People alwyas do "useless" things, especially when they don't know an alternative exists =) But my answer was ill-thought yeah, I'll edit it, thanks,

Comment: I tested your example but for this to work, the date has to be in the 'august 18, 2011 05:02' format.

Comment: @Nikolai See my edited code :) Using the method "toGMTString" on the date.

Comment: Is there a possible way to use a unix timestamp for the future date ? The reason is that the future time will be get from the db, and if it is on timestamp I will have one less column. I appreciate your help thats why I accepted your answee.

Comment: Yup, the setTime() method takes a unix timestamp as an argument.

Comment: I still can't make it working... There should be two js, jquery.js and the other?

Comment: @Nikolai let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2618/discussion-between-joshleaves-and-nikolai)

Answer (score 0):

By setting a setInterval for every second, you are basically saying that for 30 clients, you will be getting roughly 30 txn per second to your php server.  Its hard to say its a performance killer outside of just saying you will have to handle 30tps for this simple call.  I would first quesiton why you are doing this with a server side script.  You could just as easily give the html file a datetime when the page loads and do the countdown with just javascript in the browser.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I updated my question, please take a look

Answer (score 0):

I use jQuery Countdown http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html to put a timer on my pages to let the user know when they are going to be logged out of the system due to inactivity.

You can bind a function to the counter expiring event.

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-countdown/  ...Simple example

http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html  ...shows off all the bells and whistles...

It can be as simple as the first one or as detailed as the second!

-=Bryan