# How to add +9 hours on my jQuery script?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

How can I add +9 hours on my script below ? I don't prefer to just add 9 hours to the correct time, for example if I want it 13:22:54 to make it 22:22:54 for this to work but on the script.

I create the unix timestamp in a php file doing

```
$end = mktime(16, 54, 0, 8, 18, 2011);
```

and the copy it below

**Countdown Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var end_date = new Date(<?php echo $end; ?>*1000);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#time").countdown({
        date: end_date,
        onComplete: function( event ){
            $(this).html("completed");
        },
        leadingZero: true
    });
});
</script>

<p id="time" class="time"></p>
```

Comment: if you are doing it with php, why you want to do it with js? and jQuery is for DOM manipulation, not data. That's plain js you want

Comment: Because I will get the timestamp from DB

Comment: and what limits you to create the new date in php using the database date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of playing the heroes by trying to do time Math (and even failing badly), you should rely on native methods, available to both PHP and JS:

```
// gets the time 9 hours from now
// you can give a 2nd parameter to specify when is "now"
$date = strtotime('+9 hours');
```

and:

```
// get the time right now
var date = new Date()
// add 9 hours, don't worry about jumping the 24hr boundary, JS resolves correctly.
date.setHours(date.getHours()+9)
```

**Edit:**

Since the OP said he wanted to use a TS from DB, here's the relevant code:

```
$date = strtotime('+9 hours', (int)$db_time);
```

Note: If `$db_time` is a formatted string, like "24 April 2011, 4:56 pm", you need to put the following code before the one above:

```
$db_time = strtotime($db_time);
```

However, I urge you to check for alternative ways to parse the time.

Comment: Thank you for this, it really helped me on how to write my code better. For general knowledge, does this `$end = $row['ending']; ?> <script.... var end_date = new Date(<?php echo $end; ?>*1000);` is better than `<script.... var end_date = new Date(<?php echo $row['ending']; ?>*1000);` Why ?

Comment: @Nikolai - One is more readable, but the other is more concise. I wouldn't make use of a second variable just to make it a little bit easier. So I would go for the second option. By the way, for the sake of security, you should ensure `$row['ending']` is indeed an integer, with something like: `<?php echo (int)$row['ending'];`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to read between the lines here a bit. I assume based on this and previous questions that you want a countdown for some event in the future and you're pulling a timestamp from a database and adding 9 hours to it to get the time of that future event.

Assuming this, you can't use most (any?) of the previous answers because of time zones and the fact that the user's clock might be more or less off. So if you calculate on the server that the event should fire at 5 o'clock and send that info to the user who's 3 time zones away from the server, the countdown will also be 3 hours off (because when it's 5 o'clock where the user is it's either 2 or 8 o'clock where the server is.)

The solution is to calculate the time left until the event and send *that* information to the browser. This way the countdown will be independent of the user's timezone or their computer's clock. For example if the event is at 5 o'clock and it's now 4 o'clock tell the browser to put 60*60*1=3600 seconds on the timer.

Using part of Christian's answer, do something like this on the server (assuming `$db_time` contains a Unix timestamp retrieved from the database):

```
$date = strtotime('+9 hours', (int)$db_time);
$timeUntilEvent = $date - time();
```

Now `$timeUntilEvent` contains the amount of seconds until the event. In JavaScript add that number to the timer:

```
var end_date = new Date();
end_date.setTime( end_date.getTime() + <?php echo $timeUntilEvent; ?> * 1000 );
```

Now the timer will fire at the correct time regardless of what time the user's clock is set to.

Comment: Tried it but when I changed my clock the countdown changed.

Comment: Think of it this way: how probable is it that someone will change their system clock right at the same time they're viewing the site? If you're worried that the user will deliberately "speed up" the countdown, there's nothing you can do to prevent that, as [I've explained before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097534/how-to-create-a-countdown-timer-and-run-a-sql-query-with-php-when-it-is-completed/7098148#7098148). You have to add server-side checks if you don't want anyone "hacking" the countdown this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
var end_date = new Date((<?php echo $end; ?>+32400)*1000);
```

Comment: This fails for several reasons. **(1)** The OP wanted this in pure JS. **(2)** Doing it sever side means the countdown is dependent on the server date, not the clients'.

Answer (score 0):

Call this before your countdown:

```
end_date = end_date.setTime((end_date + (9 * 3600)) * 1000).toGMTString();
```

EDIT: I removed the get_time() and the "* 1000" as end_date is already a UNIX timestamp.

EDIT2: Apparently, timestamps in js are in milliseconds so we also have to multiply the PHP timestamp (which is in seconds).

Comment: No, you should be multiplying by 1000; JS timestamps are in msec not sec.

Comment: @Christian Yup but the timestamp issued by PHP is in seconds... Headache incoming... (And editing/fixing.)

Comment: I suggest you give my answer a look :)

Comment: @Christian Okay, I did "play hero" on this one :D I'm not used to javascript native functions so I go for algorithms and maths as much as I can.

Answer (score 0):

mktime returns seconds, so you simply add the desired amount of seconds

using the end_date created with php, add this line:

```
end_date+=9*60*60
```

Comment: A timestamp in javascript is based on milliseconds, not seconds. Therefor, it should be `+= 9hrs + 60mins + 6s + 1000msecs`.

Comment: i departed for the php created end_date, forgot to mention it

Answer (score 0):

```
end_date = end_date + ((3600*1000)*9);
```